# Dual of this primal optimization problem?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

How would one find the dual of the following problem?

$min_x 1/2 ||y-x||_2^2 + \lambda||x||_1 $

Can someone please explain to me how to do this since there are no specific constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reformulate your problem as
\begin{align*}
\operatorname*{minimize}_{x,u} &\quad \frac12 \|u\|_2^2 + \lambda \|x\|_1 \\
\text{subject to} &\quad u = y - x.
\end{align*}

The Lagrangian is
\begin{align*}
L(x,u,z) &= \frac12 \|u\|_2^2 + \lambda \|x\|_1 + \langle z,y-x - u \rangle \\
&= \frac12 \|u\|_2^2 - \langle z,u \rangle  + \lambda \|x\|_1 - \langle z,x \rangle + \langle z,y\rangle.
\end{align*}
The dual function is
\begin{align*}
g(z) &= \begin{cases} -\frac12 \| z \|_2^2 + \langle z,y \rangle \quad
\text{if } \|z\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda \\
-\infty \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The dual problem is
\begin{align*}
\operatorname*{maximize}_z & \quad -\frac12 \| z \|_2^2 + \langle z,y \rangle \\
\text{subject to} &\quad \|z\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda.
\end{align*}

Comment: I understand. Thanks. How would I find an explicit solution to this problem.

If I take the derivative and set to $ 0 $ I get the following: 

$ ||z||_2 = -y $ Is that it?

Comment: The dual problem is equivalent to minimize $\|z - y\|_2^2$ subject to $\|z\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda$.  So $z^*$ is the projection of $y$ onto $\lambda B$, where $B$ is the infinity norm unit ball.  From the KKT conditions we can obtain $u^* = z^*$ and $x^* = y - \text{proj}_{\lambda B}(y)$, which is the standard result for the prox operator of the $1$-norm.  A different (and simpler) way to solve the primal problem explicitly can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471339/derivation-of-soft-thresholding-operator/515930#515930).

Comment: Since we are dealing with norms, do you think you can help with this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/duality-and-convex-functions ?

It's not my question but I am quite interested in how to prove this.