# Prove that a dual norm is of the same form as the norm in original vector space.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be any norm on $E^n$. Define on $(E^n)^*$, the dual norm as follows.

$$\| a \|^* = \max \{ a \cdot x: \lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert = 1\}.$$

For every covector $a$,

(a) Verify that the dual norm satisfies properties 
$$ \| u \|^* > 0 ;\space u \ne 0 \space \text{and } \| u \|=0 \space \text{iff } u = 0$$
$$ \| cu \|^* = | c| \| u \|^*$$
$$ \| u+v \|^* \le \| u \|^* + \| v \|^* $$

(b) Show that $\| x \| = \max \{a \cdot x: \| a \|^* = 1\}$.

I could solve part (a) where I had to prove certain properties of dual norm. But I am lost on the second part. What is the question really asking? Since in the definition of $\| a \|^* $ we assumed $\| x \| = 1$, what exactly is to be calculated then for $x$

Comment: I edited your question so that the dual norm is denoted $\|\cdot\|^*$ (to be distinguished from $\|\cdot\|$). If you don't like it you can roll back the edit.

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but this looks related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/dual-to-the-dual-norm-is-the-original-norm.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you, the edit actually helps me out since the book I am referring to (Wendell Fleming: Functions of Several Variables) does not use the different notations. This clears things up a little bit and I also made some changes in my solution for part (a).

Comment: @MartinR: It does look similar, I will look into it and close the question if I can write up a good solution for this.