# Optimization involving dual norms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

The problem is 
$$
\sup_{\delta\in\mathcal{N}_0}(w^\top \delta),
$$
where $\mathcal{N}_0=\{\delta|||\delta||^*\leq c\}$ with $||\cdot||^*$ being the dual norm for an arbitrary norm.

The conclusion in a paper says the result is $c||w||$. But I don't know how to derive this result. Thanks a lot to anyone who can tell me how to deal with this kind of optimization problems with dual norms.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/dual-to-the-dual-norm-is-the-original-norm

Comment: @daw Thanks a lot! I see. $\sup (w^\top \delta)=\sup \left( \delta^\top \frac{w}{||w||} \right)||w||=||\delta||^*||w||=c||w||$.