# Prove 'dual to the dual norm is the original norm' without using Hahn-Banach theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n} .$ The associated dual norm, denoted $\|\cdot\|_{*},$ is defined as
$$
\|z\|_{*}=\sup \left\{z^{\top} x \mid\|x\| \leq 1\right\}
$$

I'm trying to prove
$$\|x\|_{**} = \|x\|$$

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/dual-to-the-dual-norm-is-the-original-norm) says we can prove it by Hahn-Banach theorem. i.e.
$$\|y\|=\max _{x \neq 0} \frac{x^{T} y}{\|y\|_{*}}$$
But I think by definition, this is what we need to prove. So it seems says 'because this is correct,
this is correct'. I think it proves nothing.

Are there any proof without using Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: The original norm $p$ and dual norm $q$ must satisfy the relation $p+q=pq$. I think this decomposition must be unique for rational $p,q$ (not sure how to prove that), therefore the dual of the dual must be the original norm. And in the case the space is endowed with some $Q$ norm, $Q\succ 0$, then the dual norm will be $Q^{-1}$, therefore the bi-dual must be $Q$ again.

Comment: @iarbel84  yes I think you are right but I want to prove a more general case, not only l-p norm or something else.

Comment: We covered $p$-norms and $Q$-norms. I agree that this is not general, but specific for $p,Q$, but what are the other norms you have in mind?

Comment: @iarbel84 Some matrix norm (spectral norm, trace norm,...) for example? For a specific norm maybe we can compute a concise expression of its dual norm, But for the general case the only expression is the definition perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- [source](https://dl.inl-lab.net/files/Courses/23-02-CO/Slides/Opt-14-Dual_Correspondence.pdf)

......................................................................................................................