# Norm equal to infimum with constraint on dual norm

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, dual-spaces

I am attempting to prove the following:

$$
-\lambda \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert = \inf_{\lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert_\ast \leq \lambda} \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{y} \; ,
$$

where $\lambda \geq 0$. I am not sure how to approach it. A proof I am trying to follow states that I can use the definition of a dual norm:

$$
\lVert \mathbf{a}\rVert_\ast = \sup_{\lVert \mathbf{b}\rVert \leq 1} \mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{b}
$$

but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help!

---

My initial guess is to formulate the norm as [Ref. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801476/prove-dual-to-the-dual-norm-is-the-original-norm-without-using-hahn-banach-the?noredirect=1&lq=1)]:
$$
\begin{aligned} \lambda \lVert\mathbf{x} \rVert &= \inf_{\mathbf{w}}\ \lambda \lVert\mathbf{w} \rVert \\
& \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \ \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{x}\;. \end{aligned}
$$
This has the corresponding Lagrangian:
$$
L(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{r}) = \lambda\lVert\mathbf{w}\rVert - \mathbf{r}^\top\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{r}^\top\mathbf{x} \;,
$$
and corresponding dual problem:
$$
\sup_{\mathbf{r}} \inf_{\mathbf{w}} \ \lambda\lVert\mathbf{w} \rVert - \mathbf{r}^\top\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{r}^\top\mathbf{x} \;.
$$
From definition of a dual norm, we know that if $\lVert\mathbf{r}\rVert_\ast > \lambda$, then $\inf_{\mathbf{w}} \left(\lambda\lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert - \mathbf{r}^\top \mathbf{w}\right) = -\infty$, and if $\lVert\mathbf{r}\rVert_\ast \leq \lambda$, then $\inf_{\mathbf{w}} \left(\lambda \lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert - \mathbf{r}^\top \mathbf{w}\right) = 0$. Therefore, the dual problem becomes:
$$
\begin{aligned} &\ \ \sup_{\mathbf{r}}\ \mathbf{r}^\top\mathbf{x} \\
& \ \ \ \ \mathrm{s.t.} \ \ \lVert\mathbf{r}\rVert_\ast \leq \lambda\;. \end{aligned}
$$
From Slater's theorem, we know that the primal problem is equal to the dual.

We then use the property that: $-\inf_{\mathbf{x}} \left( -f(\mathbf{x}) \right) = \sup_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x})$ to get that:
$$
-\lambda \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert = -\sup_{\lVert \mathbf{r}\rVert_\ast \leq \lambda} \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{r} = \inf_{\lVert \mathbf{r}\rVert_\ast \leq \lambda} \mathbf{x}^\top \left(-\mathbf{r}\right) = \inf_{\lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert_\ast \leq \lambda} \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{y} \; ,
$$
where $\mathbf{y} = - \mathbf{r}$ and therefore: $\lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert_\ast = \lVert \mathbf{r}\rVert_\ast$.

---

Proof is for Theorem 3.3.3 in: [Ruidi Chen and Ioannis Ch. Paschalidis (2020), “Distributionally Robust Learning”, : Vol. 4, No. 1–2, pp 1–243. DOI: 10.1561/2400000026](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.08993.pdf)

Comment: I think we need some extra information on $\nu$.

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I just updated the formulation to hopefully make it more clear. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: What other tools are available to you? Definitionally and since $x^Ty=y^Tx$, $|x^Ty|\leqslant \|x\|\|y\|_*$. So $x^Ty\geqslant -\lambda \|x\|$ whenever $\|y\|_*\leqslant \lambda$. Do you have access to the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: For $a>0$, let $B(a)=\{y:\|y\|_*\leqslant a\}$. Note that $B(\lambda)=\{\lambda y:y\in B(1)\}$, so $$\inf_{y\in B(\lambda)} x^Ty=\inf_{y\in B(1)} x^T(\lambda y)=\lambda \inf_{y\in B(1)} x^Ty.$$ Since $B(1)=\{-\lambda y:y\in B(1)\}$, $\inf_{y\in B(1)}x^Ty = -\sup_{y\in B(1)}x^Ty=-\|x\|_{**}$. So we've reduced the problem to showing that the dual of the dual is the original norm. In other words, $\|x\|_{**}=\|x\|$.

Comment: Hi @jwhite! Thank you for your response. I'm a bit confused about: "Since $B(1)=\{-\lambda y:y\in B(1)\}$, $\inf_{y\in B(1)}x^Ty = -\sup_{y\in B(1)}x^Ty=-\|x\|_{**}$." Isn't the definition of $B(1)$ here self-referential? Did you mean: $B(-\lambda) = \{-\lambda y:y\in B(1)\}$?

Comment: Also, for your first comment: If $\|y\|_*\leqslant \lambda$, then $ \implies |x^Ty|\leqslant \lambda\|x\| $. How did you arrive at $x^Ty\geqslant -\lambda \|x\|$?

Comment: I am also not familiar with the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: For your second question, $|a|\leqslant b$ means $-b \leqslant a \leqslant b$. Apply this with $a=x^Ty$ and $b=\lambda \|x\|$.

Comment: There was a typo in my equation (it should not contain $\lambda$). It should be $$B(1)=\{- y:y\in B(1)\}.$$ But this isn't a definition of $B(1)$. It is a property of $B(1)$, namely that it is symmetric. In other words, since $\|-y\|=\|y\|$, $y\in B(1)$ if and only if $-y\in B(1)$. So if $x^Ty= \|x\|$ with $y\in B(1)$, $-y\in B(1)$ and $x^T(-y)=-\|x\|$.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help with this. Can you explain how you got the negative sign in front of $\|x\|$ in the last part of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not familiar with the Hahn-Banach theorem, then you probably don't want to use it to solve this problem. But the Hahn-Banach theorem is fundamental to normed spaces. If $E$ is a Banach space (which every finite dimensional normed space is), if $F$ is a subspace, $R>0$ and $g:F\to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional such that $|g(x)|\leqslant R\|x\|$ for all $x\in F$, then there exists a linear extension $G:E\to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the same bound: $|G(x)|\leqslant R\|x\|$ for all $x\in E$. Let $E$ be your original space and let $x$ be any fixed non-zero vector. Let $F=\{a x:a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the span of $x$. Define $f:F\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(ax)=a\|x\|$. Then for any $ax\in F$, $|f(ax)|=|a|\|x\|=\|ax\|$. Therefore we have the desired inequality with $R=1$. We apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to find some linear extension $G:E\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|G(z)|\leqslant \|z\|$ for all $z$. We then note that $G$ has the form $G(z)=z^Ty$ for some $y$. Then $|z^Ty|=|G(z)|\leqslant \|z\|\leqslant 1$ for any $z$ with $\|z\|\leqslant 1$. From this it follows that $\|y\|_*\leqslant 1$. And $x^Ty=G(x)=g(x)=\|x\|$. So $$\|x\|_{**} =\sup_{\|y'\|_*\leqslant 1}x^Ty' \geqslant x^Ty=\|x\|.$$

We show the other inequality $\|x\|_{**}\leqslant \|x\|$, which is elementary. If $x=0$, then $\|0\|_{**}=\|0\|=0$. Assume $x\neq 0$. Note that, with $u=x/\|x\|$, $\|u\|=1$. For any $y$ with $\|y\|_*\leqslant 1$, $$x^Ty=(\|x\|u)^Ty=\|x\|u^Ty\leqslant \|x\|\sup_{\|x'\|\leqslant 1}=\|x\|\|y\|_*\leqslant \|x\|.$$  Since this holds for any $y$ with $\|y\|_*\leqslant 1$, it holds that $$\|x\|_{**}=\sup_{\|y\|_*\leqslant 1}x^Ty\leqslant \|x\|.$$

Thus $\|x\|_{**}=\|x\|$ for any $x$.

Let $B=\{y:\|y\|_*\leqslant 1\}$ and note that $y\in B$ if and only if $-y\in B$. Therefore $$\{x^Ty:y\in B\}=\{x^T(-y):y\in B\}=\{-x^Ty:y\in B\}.$$ Thus the set of values $\{x^Ty:y\in B\}$ is symmetric, and the supremum of this set is the opposite of the infimum of this set. That is, $$\sup_{\|y\|_*\leqslant 1}x^Ty=\sup\{x^Ty:y\in B\} = -\inf\{x^Ty:y\in B\}=-\|x\|_{**}=-\|x\|.$$

Last, for $\lambda>0$, $\{y:\|y\|_*\leqslant \lambda\}=\{\lambda y:\|y\|_*\leqslant 1\}$. Thus $$\sup_{\|y\|_*\leqslant \lambda}x^Ty=\sup_{\|y\|_*\leqslant 1}x^T(\lambda y)=\lambda \sup_{\|y\|_*\leqslant 1}x^Ty=\lambda \|x\|_{**}=\lambda \|x\|.$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up! For $-\inf_{x} \left\{ x^Ty : y \in B \right\}$, couldn't we take $y$ to be a vector of zeros and then the infimum would be zero? I'm confused how we can say that the supremum of the set is the opposite of the infimum of the set? Nvm,.... 0 isn't the infimum, we can go negative. I guess my question is why is $\inf_{x} \left\{ x^Ty : y \in B \right\} = \|x\|$?

Comment: We have the following steps: Step $1$: $-\inf \{x^Ty:y\in B\}=\sup \{x^Ty:y\in B\}$ by symmetry. 

Step $2$: $\sup \{x^Ty:y\in B\}=\sup_{\|y\|_*\leqslant 1} x^Ty=\|x\|_{**}$ by the definition of $B$ for first equality and by definition of the dual norm for second. 

Step $3$: $\|x\|_{**}=\|x\|$ by the first two pieces of the answer above.