# Do primal and dual norms bound each other, that is, $\|\cdot\| \leq \|\cdot\|_\star$?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

Given a norm $\|\cdot\|$, the dual norm is by definition,
$$
\|y\|_* 
= 
\max\limits_{x} \ x^Ty
\quad \text{subject to} \quad
\|x\| \le 1
$$

Does there exist some bound between the primal and dual norm in the same way that $l_p$ and $l_q$ norms are related?

That is, can we show $\|\cdot\| \leq \|\cdot\|_\star$ and vice versa?

Comment: I think [the dual norm of the dual norm is the primal norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/dual-norm-of-the-dual-norm-is-the-primal-norm). So if $\|\cdot \| \le \|\cdot \|_*$ held in general, then so would the opposite inequality, which would together imply equality. So I don't think  your inequality holds in general.

Comment: @angryavian Can I say something, that there exist $c_1, c_2 > 0$ such that $c_1 \|\cdot\|_\star \leq \|\cdot\| \leq c_2 \|\cdot\|_\star$.

Comment: Which space are you working with?  Some arbitrary inner product space?

Comment: In finite dimensions, all norms are equivalent.