# An accessible proof of the fact that the dual of the dual norm is the norm itself

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{F}$ ($=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and $\|\cdot \|$ a norm on $V$. Define
$$\|x\|^* \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} \sup_{\|y\| \leqslant 1} |\langle x, y\rangle|$$
for every $x\in V$. Note that the sup exists and is a max since $y \mapsto |\langle x, y\rangle|$ is continuous as a map from $(V, \|\cdot \|)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot |)$ for every $x\in V$ and $\{y \in V :\|y\| \leqslant 1\}$ is a compact subset of $(V, \|\cdot \|)$. Consequently,
$$\|x\|^* = \max_{\|y\|\leqslant 1} |\langle x, y\rangle | = \max_{\|y\| = 1}|\langle x, y\rangle | = \max_{0\neq y\in V}\frac{|\langle x,  y\rangle |}{\|y\|}$$
for every $x\in V$. Further, $\|\cdot \|^*$ is a norm on $V$, a fact that can easily be verified.

Is it true that $\|\cdot \|^{**} = \|\cdot \|$? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/dual-norm-of-the-dual-norm-is-the-primal-norm) page seems to suggest so (note that the definition in this post is slightly more general). If yes, is there a proof of this fact that is accessible to undergraduates who have merely seen some linear algebra and real analysis?

Proving that $\|\cdot \|^{**} \leqslant \|\cdot \|$ is easy: Fix $x\in V$. Pick $y\in V$ with $\|y\|^* = 1$ such that $\|x\|^{**} = |\langle x, y\rangle|$ and observe that
$$\|x\|^{**} = |\langle x, y\rangle | \leqslant \|x\|\|y\|^* = \|x\|.$$

Comment: In the original definition, are the norm and the inner product related? You say “a norm.”

Comment: No, they aren't. $\|\cdot\|$ is an arbitrary norm on $V$.

Comment: Yes, I get that. I just thought you should make it explicit for the general audience. :) Indeed, you need to apply the definition next with the norm $\|\cdot\|^*$. I don't see an obvious easy proof.

Comment: By the way, why should undergraduates (or even I, a retired professional mathematician) even care about this? What's an interesting application/motivation?